# How can I use the scroll lock key to toggle the back light on my keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently purchased a backlit keyboard that requires Scroll Lock for toggling the lights. I quickly came into some issues that can be worked around with a few simple bash commands - See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164245/why-is-the-scroll-lock-key-disabled-in-cinnamon-linux-xorg) thread.

In short, the command I found that fixed this issue was:

```
xset led named "Scroll Lock"
```

To enabled Scroll Lock (and turn the lights on), and

```
xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
```

To disable Scroll Lock and turn the lights off.

What options are available if I want to issue the former command if a Scroll Lock key event is received and the (Scroll Lock) function is turned off, and the latter in the other case? That is,

```
if(ScrollLockIsEnabled)
    systemCommand('xset -led named "Scroll Lock");
else
    systemCommand('xset led named "Scroll Lock"`);
```

Or similar.

I was thinking, at the very least, perhaps doing some sort of a Bash script that kept a variable (if possible) that allowed me to retain the last state of Scroll Lock. I could then execute this script using `xbindkeys` (which issues commands based on key events input by the user).

Answer (score 3):

Found this after searching for a similar problem. Since it is a year old I might as well answer it anyway.

As in the question if you use `xset led named "Scroll Lock"` it will enable leds and `xset -led named "Scroll Lock"` will disable the keyboard leds. If you examine the `xset --help` it mentions that `xset q` prints out the current status information.

Here is a truncated sample of the stdout in the terminal:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000002
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
```

The string `Scroll lock: off` will only be present in the output if and only if the Scroll Lock is off, so we can use grep to check for this string.
`xset q | grep "Scroll Lock: off"` works just fine for our purposes. Then, in a shell script we can check for the null string to see when it is on.

```
#!/bin/sh

result=$(xset q | grep "Scroll Lock: off")
if [ -z "$result" ]; then # Scroll Lock must be on
  echo "Off"
  xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
else
  echo "On"
  xset led named "Scroll Lock"
fi
```

Then if you want to, just use your window manager or desktop environment configuration to execute this script when you press scroll lock.

Answer (score 3):

just using bash, U can do this, i use this on a scroll lock backlit keyboard. must be run as root

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "this program requires root user" 2>&1
    exit 1
fi

dir1=$(find /sys/devices/ -name brightness | grep scrolllock)
while :
do
    var1=`cat $dir1`
    if [ $var1 == 0 ] ; then
        echo 1 > $dir1
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

I use this in root crontab

```
@reboot sh ~/sh/backlight.sh &
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, but here is a single line command:

```
xset q | grep -q 'Scroll Lock: off' && xset led named 'Scroll Lock' || xset -led named 'Scroll Lock'
```

Use this with xbindkeys or with sxhkd (modern)

I hope this helps someone today, knowing these keyboards aren't that common anymore.